# Default React Component not rendering (Create-React-App)

Tags: reactjs

UPDATE: This problem has been solved by simply using a different browser. I was originally using Microsoft Edge as that is what NPM Start automatically opened. For some reason it appears to work perfectly when manually pasting localhost:3000/ into Chrome.

I am brand new to React and I am trying to set up a basic test project.
I have been following some tutorials, this one in particular https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBws8MSXN7A
My issue is that for some reason when I try to test the basic boilerplate I don't see anything from the basic component. From what I understand there should just be a basic logo, but my page is completely blank. I don't know what code is relevant to post since I am very new so if you think something might help then let me know what you would like.

Here is what I have done:

In Windows Powershell I ran npx create-react-app todolist

This created a new react app in a folder called todolist.

I moved into the todolist folder in Powershell using the cd command.

From here I ran npm start

This opened a new microsoft edge window at localhost:3000/ 
It has the title of React App on the tab, but there is no content on the page.

From what I understand there should be a logo here.

I opened the console and it says this:

HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
localhost:3000 (1,1)

[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: SyntaxError
0.chunk.js (3857,1)

I don't know if that is relevant but I might as well add it.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I have been Googling about this for over an hour and cannot figure out what is going on.

Comment: Does your website load correctly in other browsers?

Comment: Yes it does.... When I put localhost:3000/ into my chrome browser the page appears to load as intended. For some reason Edge didn't work. Damn do I feel dumb for not thinking to try that. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: i tried to find a solution for this and i tried the suggested solutions and none worked. From what I'm seeing react simply doesn't support Edge. I've installed the polyfill and imported it to index.js and nothing. wrote this comment to receive notification if a solution was found for this

Answer (score 1):

1. delete your `node_modules` folder
2. update your `package.json`

```
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version",
  "ie 11" // <-- add this
]
```

3. run `npm i`

Comment: I tried this and it still did not work on edge. I have been able to get it to work using Chrome though.

Comment: try using the values from `"production"` property.